# Openstack Horizon Customization

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I have deployed openstack (zed version) using kolla installation as a learning experience in a Centos 9 machine. I am trying to customize horizon dashboard so specific roles wont see certain panels.

For example i want to hide the panel "Routers" inside the "Network" tab for users with the role "student".

I have tried:

**1.** To create an "overrides.py" and customized "local_settings.py" file to run the code. I can hide the panel "Routers" for all users but not for specific roles (did not find any info if it can happend).

Change in **local_settings.py**:

```
HORIZON_CONFIG["customization_module"] = "my_project.overrides"
```

Code i tried for **overrides.py**:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

import horizon

projects_dashboard = horizon.get_dashboard("project")
images_panel = projects_dashboard.get_panel("routers")
projects_dashboard.unregister(images_panel.__class__)
```

**2.** To Customize policy rules like "/etc/openstack-dashboard/neutron_policy.yaml", but i only found commands to disable certain buttons like create,update or delete a router etc.